# Kotlin: create a map from a list using index

Tags: kotlin

I have a list as follows:

```
val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

I want to create a map such that each index goes to each value of the list.

1 to "one", 2 to "two", ..

I want the result to be a

```
Map<Int, String>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the ways could be:

```
numbers.mapIndexed { index: Int, s: String -> index + 1 to s }.toMap()
```

Comment: I believe the OP needs it as `index+1 to s`

Answer (score 8):

numbers.withIndex().associateBy ({ it.index }, {it.value})

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
val numbersMaps = (0 until numbers.size).map { i ->
   i+1 to numbers[it]
}
println(numbersMaps)
```

Comment: This is good, but the type returned in numbersMaps is List<Pair<Int,String> I'm looking for a Map<Int,String>

Comment: Needs a `.toMap()` at the end. `(0 until numbers.size)` could be replaced with `numbers.indices`. Also, `it` should be `i`.